# How to make a code ask the same question until a user guesses the word correctly using Python?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, module

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

word = "trick or treat"     # This is the phrase a user needs to guess
prompts = chain(
    ["You meet a whitch with a cauldron full of candies, what do you say? \n"], repeat("Noope! "))
replies = map(input, prompts)
valid_response = next(filter(word.__contains__, replies))
print(valid_response)
```

Error:

```
"Chain has not attribute %s" % ident
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why are you using `chain()`, `map()` and `next()`?  Did someone tell you those were a good solution?  Did you read that somewhere?  Or did you come up with those on your own?

Comment: No, I've tried to search for a solution )))

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a `while` loop:

```
word = "trick or treat"
while True:
    reply = input("You meet a witch with a cauldron full of candies, what do you say? \n")
    if word not in reply:
        print("Noope!")
    else:
        print("Correct!")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot, simple for me to understand, yet it works! )))

Comment: Great! Please make sure to also accept the answer, as per Stack Overflow guidelines!